# inputAccessoryView from UISearchBar

Tags: iphone

How can I access to `inputAccessoryView` propery from `UISearchBar`? I mean there's no `UITextField` property in `UISearchBar` that by it I could  access to `inputAccessoryView`.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat a little here, though I think iOS 6 makes this assignable now. Anyway something like this:

```
for (UIView* v in _mySearchBar.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        ((UITextField*)v).inputAccessoryView = _inputToolbarAccessory;
    }
}
```

Things like this can be dangerous if Apple changes the way they designed that particular widget, but I find myself doing it more often than I probably should.